# Logical operation on an array in DOCplex

Tags: cplex, python, logical-constraints, docplex

Here is a simple example of logical operation in docplex taken from  [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=b8ca2821-3f08-4cf2-a4c7-55253f5265fe). Code below works fine.

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

m = Model("test")

a = m.binary_var(name="a")
b = m.binary_var(name="b")
c = m.binary_var(name="c")

m.add_constraint(m.logical_and(a, b) == c)
m.add_constraint(a == 1)
m.add_constraint(b == 0)

if m.solve():
    m.print_solution(print_zeros=True)
else:
    print(m.solve_details)
```

Just for the purpose of testing, I created an array of a binary variable. Code below gives compilation error:

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

m = Model("test")

w = {k: m.binary_var(name="w_{0}".format(k)) for k in range(10)}
c = m.binary_var(name="c")

m.add_constraint(m.logical_and(w[k] for k in range(10)) == c)

if m.solve():
    m.print_solution(print_zeros=True)
else:
    print(m.solve_details)
```

Error:

```
docplex.mp.utils.DOcplexException: Model.logical_and, arg#0: Not a logical operand: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fd373a8f410>. Expecting binary variable, logical expression
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument in `logical_and` is `*args` but it's not unpacked in the subroutines inside of `logical_and`. Your error will be gone if you change the following line from

`m.add_constraint(m.logical_and(w[k] for k in range(10)) == c)`

to

`m.add_constraint(m.logical_and(*(w[k] for k in range(10))) == c)`